# More general lattices on the complex plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-forms, integer-lattices, lattices-in-lie-groups

I have learned that lattices defined on the complex plane can be defined by $\mathbb Z\tau_1\oplus\mathbb Z\tau_2$, where $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\mathbb C$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$. I have also learned that $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$ and $(\tau_1',\tau_2')$ define the same lattice when: 
$$(\tau_1',\tau_2')=(a\tau_1+b\tau_2,c\tau_1+d\tau_2)$$ For $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.

I'm wondering what the more general form of this is. I don't know what the technical term is, but let's call $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ the "Lattice Transition Group" of $\mathbb C$, in that it defines all isomorphisms between lattices in $\mathbb C$.

If we fix the lattice transition group of some group $G$ as $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$, what can be said of $G$? Is there even a group for every $n$ (or even any $n>2$?) that would satisfy this property? If so, what are the properties of this group?

Comment: $G = \mathbb{R}^n$ works for each $n$, not sure about the existence of other groups.

Comment: @user263190 Any reference for how I can generalize the first statement above to $R^n$, i.e prove that two lattices are the same if the $\tau_n$'s used to define them are equal relative to $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: A lattice is nothing more than the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of a $\mathbb{R}$-basis. Given any basis, you want to know which linear transformations will preserve the integer span. To be contained in the integer span the matrix needs to be integer, and to actually preserve it it needs to be invertible. Also, I just realized, I think you want $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ instead of $SL_2$, since, for example, $(1, \tau)$ and $(1, -\tau)$ give the same lattice.